# Issues with migration AzureRm to Az

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-rm, az

Currently, I am working on refactoring code to move from AzureRM to Az module, but I have been blocked for some time on one strange thing. 
I have already changed all the commands to Az module and everything works smoothly locally.

But the issue starts when I try to run this powershell script from Azure DevOps
I've attached a small part of the code, which is the main problem point of my code. From Azure, DevOps code runs successfully, but it doesn't perform the action from this script block. It's quite important to run it as a background job ( asynchronously ) but Az module somehow is causing issues ( or maybe something else ).

Previously ( with AzureRM module )the same part of code worked like a charm.

I have the same Az module and PowerShell versions on both, local pc and Azure DevOps agents.

Any ideas why script block is not performing any actions?

Any help appreciated! 
Cheers!

Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    param($resourceGroupName, $deployment)
    Remove-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $deployment.DeploymentName
} -ArgumentList @($resourceGroup, $deployment) | Out-Null

Comment: Hi Hugh Lin. 
Sadly no. I understand, that maybe it's bit too less information I provided, but I am not allowed to give you more, I can just try to explain. I tried Bevan's solutions before I created this post, but still no success. Could it be the issue, that I have both Az module and AzureRM installed on the Azure DevOps agents at the same time? But I think it shouldn't be the issue as if I do command:

Remove-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $deployment.DeploymentName

without script block, It runs fine ( so Az module works ).

Answer (score 0):

One point to note is that you need to select the **4.*(preview) version** for Azure PowerShell task which support Az Module.

For now Az module is [only support with v4 of the Azure Powershell task](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/3869).
Since Azure PowerShell – Cross-platform “Az” module replacing “AzureRM” is a trend.

You could also find the open source source code for V4 Azure Powershell task in GitHub: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/AzurePowerShellV4

Comment: Hi, Hugh Lin!
Thanks for the assistance! 
I'm already using 4.*(preview) version for Azure Powershell task which is having Az module installed. It shows asynchronous job started and waits for them to complete and then removes them successfully, modules seems working but in reality still nothing happens when running from Azure DevOps agents

Answer (score 0):

It's something to do with your arguments I think. There's a mismatch with arg, parameter and variable usage in the command between $resourceGroupName and $resourceGroup

By the looks of your usage it seems that $resourceGroup is a string and $deployment is an array. If that's the case then your args  should be `-ArgumentList @($deployment),$resourceGroup`

Full snippet

`Start-Job -ScriptBlock { param($deployment, $resourceGroup) Remove-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $deployment.DeploymentName
} -ArgumentList @($deployment),$resourceGroup | Out-Null`

The amount of info provided isn't great though. I'd just try running the `Remove-AzResourceGroupDeployment` command without the job as an initial test. This will tell you if it's the Az module or or your job. Also, I've had problems with modules loading on hosted agents in the past so try `install-module Az.Resources -force -allowclobber`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and assistance Bevan, 

I tried everything mentioned above, but still no success.
But I also have this feeling, that issue is hidden within arguments. 

resourceGroup is a string. 
deployment variable is an object. It has values like Lenght, DeploymentName etc.

Comment: You could try skipping the args altogether: `Start-Job -ScriptBlock {Remove-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $using:resourceGroup -Name $using:deployment.DeploymentName }`. Could also try putting your script into a variable and invoking it with `invoke-command $command -asjob`